# Declarative injection of Chrome Extension Content into a frame with src="javascript''"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to inject a javascript file into a frame of a website. I am trying to be specific on which iframe it is injected into as the website has many.  The frame looks like this

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" name="uploaddocframe-4345" class="x-docform-component" frameborder="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" id="uploaddocframe-4345"></iframe>
```

I therefore started with the following in the manifest;

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["javascript*"],
  "all_frames": true,
  "js": [ "myframejs.js" ]
}
```

]

Chrome does not like this and will not load the extension.

It is probably my lack of understanding of HTML/javascript and web development and less about chrome extensions but how can I target this frame in my manifest?

Comment: This is a so-called "about:blank" iframe which doesn't have its own matchable URL as "javascript:" is not a valid standalone URL, it effectively just inherits its parent page/frame's URL. To load a content script there specifically you'll have to declare a background script with chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted listener where you'll check the details.url and details.frameId, then use chrome.tabs.executeScript with those frameId and tabId.

Comment: Alternatively you can inject your content script in all such iframes indiscriminately by changing "matches" to the site's URL pattern and adding ["match_about_blank": true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively).

Comment: If I understand webNavigation.onCommitted the url in my case would be "javascript" and the frameId would be a chrome extension generated ID and not the actual iframe id in the page. As such I would then need to always use executeScript to learn the actual ID. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. The primary use of a frameId !== 0 check is to ensure the navigation is for an iframe.

Comment: Actually, it might make more sense to inject a single content script on the main URL and just check the iframes either periodically or by using a MutationObserver.

Comment: Great idea. I am familiar with MutationObservers. So I think I have 3 options. I dont want to be slowing down the webpage so I am unsure which in theory is the best. A MutationObserver will be running all the time. Injecting a JS script at document_idle for a few frames seems like it would be more efficient over time. I dont like the onCommitted event.